# How do I install Openvpn Keys?

Tags: vpn

How do I get the keys & certificate to work on openvpn client? I have been given those by the VPN provider. But openvpn needs more than user key & cert?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download file cert.pem from OpenVPN Server. (System Admin can help you.)
2. Install OpenVPN Client.

   `sudo apt-get install openvpn`
3. If you put your cert.pem on this path /home/your_account_name/openvpn-client/cert.pem when you connect by OpenVPN client you must use this command :

   `sudo openvpn –client –pull –comp-lzo –nobind –dev tap0 –ca /home/your_account_name/openvpn-client/cert.pem –auth-user-pass –remote Your_IP_Of_OpenVPN_Server`

** This command has one line.

4 . It’s complete.

Reference: http://gregoryreese.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/how-do-configure-the-openvpn-client-on-ubuntu-story-of-aoddy/

hope this helps.